# PWA not loading after refresh in offline mode

Tags: react-router, progressive-web-apps, workbox

Im currently working on understanding PWA. Im building one as a SPA using react router.
The PWA works fine when using offline mode on Chrome on my PC. I can refresh, navigate and use the app.

When i do the same on my Phone however, my PWA does not work after pull-to-refresh. It just shows the offline dinosaur.

Im suspecting it somehow has something todo with how i register my routes. I hope somebody here knows why this strange behaviour is occuring.

my manifest

```
{
  "short_name": "Bierlympiade",
  "name": "Bierlympiade",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "favicon.ico",
      "sizes": "64x64 32x32 24x24 16x16",
      "type": "image/x-icon"
    },
    {
      "src": "logo192.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "192x192"
    },
    {
      "src": "logo512.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "index.html",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "#ffffff"
}
```

my serviceworker (generated)

```
/// <reference lib="webworker" />
/* eslint-disable no-restricted-globals */

// This service worker can be customized!
// See https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules
// for the list of available Workbox modules, or add any other
// code you'd like.
// You can also remove this file if you'd prefer not to use a
// service worker, and the Workbox build step will be skipped.

import { clientsClaim } from 'workbox-core';
import { ExpirationPlugin } from 'workbox-expiration';
import { precacheAndRoute, createHandlerBoundToURL } from 'workbox-precaching';
import { registerRoute } from 'workbox-routing';
import { StaleWhileRevalidate } from 'workbox-strategies';

declare const self: ServiceWorkerGlobalScope;

clientsClaim();

// Precache all of the assets generated by your build process.
// Their URLs are injected into the manifest variable below.
// This variable must be present somewhere in your service worker file,
// even if you decide not to use precaching. See https://cra.link/PWA
precacheAndRoute(self.__WB_MANIFEST);

// Set up App Shell-style routing, so that all navigation requests
// are fulfilled with your index.html shell. Learn more at
// https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/architecture/app-shell
const fileExtensionRegexp = new RegExp('/[^/?]+\\.[^/]+$');
registerRoute(
  // Return false to exempt requests from being fulfilled by index.html.
  ({ request, url }: { request: Request; url: URL }) => {
    // If this isn't a navigation, skip.
    if (request.mode !== 'navigate') {
      return false;
    }

    // If this is a URL that starts with /_, skip.
    if (url.pathname.startsWith('/_')) {
      return false;
    }

    // If this looks like a URL for a resource, because it contains
    // a file extension, skip.
    if (url.pathname.match(fileExtensionRegexp)) {
      return false;
    }

    // Return true to signal that we want to use the handler.
    return true;
  },
  createHandlerBoundToURL(process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/index.html')
);

// An example runtime caching route for requests that aren't handled by the
// precache, in this case same-origin .png requests like those from in public/
registerRoute(
  // Add in any other file extensions or routing criteria as needed.
  ({ url }) => url.origin === self.location.origin && url.pathname.endsWith('.png'),
  // Customize this strategy as needed, e.g., by changing to CacheFirst.
  new StaleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: 'images',
    plugins: [
      // Ensure that once this runtime cache reaches a maximum size the
      // least-recently used images are removed.
      new ExpirationPlugin({ maxEntries: 50 }),
    ],
  })
);

// This allows the web app to trigger skipWaiting via
// registration.waiting.postMessage({type: 'SKIP_WAITING'})
self.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
  if (event.data && event.data.type === 'SKIP_WAITING') {
    self.skipWaiting();
  }
});

// Any other custom service worker logic can go here.
```

Comment: I am also facing the same issue.. did you found any solution ?